# Detecting touch on SVGKit's SVGKImageView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, svgkit

I have started using this great `SVGKit` for iOS. I am using a subclass of `SVGKImageView`. Now before subclassing `SVGKImageView` i have been easily able to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it. But my requirement made me to use subclasses as i have to place tens of `SVGKImageView`on to my parent view.

(*This is because there would be `SVGKImageView`transparent portions on other views and i want to be able to ignore touches on the views areas where alpha = 0 so i want to be able to detect touch on a single `SVGKImageView` then check for alpha value and if touch is on transparent area forward the touch event to the next view and so on until non transparent area of some view found*)

Now after subclassing the `SVGKImageView`adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not work, also this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

is not called in my subclass. I have also set SVGKImageView's `userInteractionEnabled` to YES but of no avail.

Can anyone help tell me that why there is no touch/tap event being passed to my
`SVGKImageView` subclass?

Below is my subclass `init` method

```
- (instancetype)init{

    self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(svgImageTapped:)];
    self.tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];

    self.imageSVG = [SVGKImage imageNamed:@"SomeFile.svg"];
    self = (Subclass*)[[SVGKLayeredImageView alloc] initWithSVGKImage:self.imageSVG];
    [self sizeToFit];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let order your code:

```
- (instancetype)init{
        self = [super init]; // <--- should go first

        self = (Subclass*)[[SVGKLayeredImageView alloc] initWithSVGKImage:[SVGKImage imageNamed:@"SomeFile.svg"]];

        // self.imageSVG = [SVGKImage imageNamed:@"SomeFile.svg"];
        [self sizeToFit];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        return self;
}
```

Comment: I have tested with and without `UITapGestureRecognizer` but to no avail. also [tapGestureRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:NO]; of no use

Comment: Does the gesture get callback?

Comment: alloc init with a nil image pointer will lead to crash don't you think?

Comment: Sorry, edited again. I think the problem is self = [super init]; , you should call it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87764/discussion-between-umair-and-anhtu).